# Python regex for the following expression

Tags: python, regex

I have the string

```
s = 'const char * const xyz = \"abc\"'
```

that I want run regex on .

I'm using

```
match = re.search(r'const char * const (\w+) = (\w+)', s)
```

to catpure `xyz` and `abc` part of the string but i'm getting a `None` object back

What am I doing wrong

Comment: You're missing the quotes around the value

Comment: I hope you're using regex to replace your `const char*` with a `std::string` :)

Comment: I don't think quotes helped

Comment: @user3711096 what is your resulting regex?  Also keep in mind the difference between `s = '` and `s = r'` if you want to preserve the backslashes

Comment: also need to escape the '*' after `char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't matching against the double quotes in the string literal.  The code below fixes that.

```
import re
s = 'const char * const xyz = \"abc\"'
match = re.search(r'const char \* const (\w+) = \"(\w*)\"', s)
```

However, you're only going to match strings literals include `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` with `\w`.  The following is more inclusive.  It matches anything that isn't a double quote up to the next double quote:

```
match = re.search(r'const char \* const (\w+) = \"([^\"]*)\"', s)
```

But it won't match strings that have embedded double quotes, like `'The \"Black Crowes\" played in L.A. last weekend.'` To do something like that, try:

```
match = re.search(r'const char \* const (\w+) = \"((\\?.)*?)\"', s)

>>> match.group(1)
'xyz'
>>> match.group(3)
'abc'
```

Starting at `"`: This matches the beginning double-quote for the string literal.  `((\\?.)*?)`: lazy match slashes plus another character (or just another character) for 0 or more times until we encounter `"`.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering the double quotes in the string literal would be rendered as it is and that we don't have to escape it

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the double quotes :

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)\s=\s"(\w+)"',s)
[('xyz', 'abc')]
```

Or use `re.search` :

```
>>> p=re.search(r'(\w+)\s=\s"(\w+)"',s)
>>> p.group(1)
'xyz'
>>> p.group(2)
'abc'
```